# Rotation and circle equation proof correction

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need to prove, that an equation of a circle doesn't change if there's a rotation.

So, I start with $$x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

and by replacing my values of $x$ and $y$ with

$$x=x'\cos\theta-y'\sin\theta$$ and $$y=x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta$$

which I arrive to this equation $$x'^2+y'^2+Gx'+Hy'+F=0$$

My question is, that I don't know if I have proved what I wanted to prove.

Comment: What formulas for $G,H$ in terms of $D,E,F$ ?

Comment: If the center of rotation is not in the center of the circle, the statement is wrong. (You would have $G\neq D$ or $E \neq H.$)